# why isn't my activity class's instance variable value being preserved onResume()?

Tags: android

1. I have a listview in Activity B populated by a list of lists through an adapter.  This list of lists was retrieved from a bundle passed by Activity A like so:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
   lvLineups = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvResults); 
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   lineups = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Band>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("results");
   ResultsAdapter resultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this, lineups);
   lvLineups.setAdapter(resultsAdapter);
   }
   ```
2. I launch an implicit video intent from this activity so Activity B goes in the background(paused, onPause invoked) and the video goes in the front.
3. I click back on the video, killing that activity.
4. Activity B's resumes(onResume is called) and I see that the list of lists(lineups) is now empty.  **According to the activity lifecyle, this activity is resuming so why don't I still see the list of lists in step 1, and how do I preserve it after the implicit video intent.**

Note:  This looks like a vertical listview where each row is a horizontally scrolling list.  I've gotten this layout to work except when adding the video intent.  Playing a video and scrolling down causes an indexoutofbounds exception because lineups, the bundle received from Activity A, is now gone.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

    lvLineups = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvResults);
    lineups = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Band>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("results");
    ResultsAdapter resultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this, lineups);
    lvLineups.setAdapter(resultsAdapter);
}
```

after the media player plays the video and closes, returning to Activity B, I see in the debugger that lineups is empty.  This is strange because it is an uninitialized instance variable before onCreate is called.  I expected it to remain the same after the video intent is launched from Activity B, or at least be null.

Comment: Post the code where you're setting the adapter to listview. You're getting data from `A`. So you need to store them somewhere to re-use in `B`.

Comment: are you storing those values in `onPause()` of `B`?

Comment: Probably you don't need to do anything with your adapter in `onResume()` or `onPause()` at all, but this suggestion is moot until you post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Let us go through the activity cycle.

Initially you started Activity B from Activity A => So the `lineups` is fetched from the bundle of activity A. So you get that value.

Then you launched the `Video` which is another intent. Then you are going back. At this point the `onResume()` gets called again (Where the bundle has no value for `lineups`). You  should get the `lineups` in `onCreate()` rather than  `onResume()` which gets called after a pause.

Comment: I initially put the getSerializableExra call in onCreate, not onResume in Activity B and had the same result; when the video ends and the activity resumes, the value of lineups is lost.  I need to preserve this somehow; I thought since activity B is in the background while video is playing that upon return the value would still be kept.

Comment: Try removing every thing initializing the lineups from onResume and put a log and check whether onCreate() is getting called and log the value of the list as well

Comment: Removed onResume and put that code in onCreate.  It gets called once, before the video is played.  After the video is played and control goes back to Activity B, I see the once full list empty(size 0 but not null).

Comment: Can you post your latest code as a comment. including where ever you use this list

Comment: I reposted the onCreate at the end of my original question; thanks

Comment: Ok, do one thing , debug with current code and within `onResume()` check the value of the list before and after video. Use debug also put a debug point in `onCreate()` to make sure that it's getting called once. During some configuration changes there is a chance that activity can get restarted

Comment: thanks viswanath, it was a different, silly mistake.